# ng-grid flexible height plugin and fixed header

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I implemented the flexible height plugin to enable ng-grid to grow and shrink when it's container grows and contracts - no problems there. However, now the fixed header is no longer fixed. Anyone ever run across this issue?

Comment: can you provide a working example using jsfiddle or Plunker?

Comment: Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/SG3B77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
.ngHeaderScroller{
   position:fixed;
}
```

to your css and this should work.

[Forked Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ajrtD4paUGX41bvRG82r?p=preview)

Comment: As a follow up to this - the fixed position worked fine until the table/grid moved of course. I still can't find a way to keep the header fixed in place relative to its container. I ended up having to hack my animation routine to toggle the fixed position style. Works, but it feels dirty.